# Are generated subgroups of rings closed under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm wondering, if the generated subgroups $\langle f\rangle$ of a polynomial ring $R[X]$ are also closed under addition. In grouptheory they are obviously closed under multiplication (or the group operation), since $\langle f\rangle = \{f^0,f^1,f^2,\ldots\}$, but in ring theory we have two operations, and then the closure under addition (if there is) isn't clear to me.

So in other words: Is $\langle f\rangle$ a subgroup or a subring?

Comment: You forgot closure under *inverses!* In any case: the multiplicative structure of a ring is not a group, it is a monoid (if you require identities) or a semigroup (if you do not). You usually do not talk about "subgroup" of a semigroup, so it makes no sense to ask about "subgroup" in the multiplicative case if you don't require unities. If you do require unities, it would only make sense if you are asking for a subgroup of the multiplicative monoid, in which case it would only work if $f$ is a unit. So, in general, it only makes sense under addition,, in which case it is $\{nf\mid n\in Z\}$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you :) I'd be happy to give you the "answer tick", if you want to make that an answer :)